# scratch org creation gives error on proxy

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, salesforcedx-cli-auth

> > sfdx force:org:create -s -f ./config/project-scratch-def.json -a AppScratch

using above command for scratch org creation gives error on proxy

> > ERROR:  location is not defined.

[image]

i have tried to set http proxy and https proxy according to the below salesforce doccumentation
[Use the Salesforce CLI from Behind a Company Firewall or Web Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm)

please share if someone has more knowledge on it or has faced the similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you have included the wrong location.

You should change your command from

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f ./config/project-scratch-def.json -a AppScratch
```

to

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f /config/project-scratch-def.json -a AppScratch
```

Just remove the dot before the config path and this will solve your problem.